# Reset hyperlink to 'new' from 'active'

Tags: libreoffice, html

I don't know what I've done, but hyperlinks color has changed from blue to black. How can I undo this? This is LibreOffice 7.3.2.2 30(Build:2)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You probobly clicked it - links change color when they are clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I don't know what I've done, but hyperlinks color has changed from blue to black. " As someone perspicaciously pointed out, "that's because you clicked on the link", changing its status from 'new' to 'active'. One way to revert it is to

1. edit the link
2. copy it,
3. remove it,
4. remove formatting, and
5. insert the link anew

UPDATE: it can be done faster simply with stage 1 (and click on OK).

In any case, one can't bulk do that.

Answer (score 0):

Styles menu > Manage Styles

Right click on "Internet Link" > Modify...

Click on the "Font Effects" tab

Change font colour to #000080

Click "Apply"

The above steps are to change the global default for new hyperlinks.

If you just need to change the colour for an existing hyperlink, then it's this:-

Click-drag to select the hyperlink you want to change

Format > Character

Click the "Font Effects" tab

Click the "Font Colour" drop down menu

Select "Custom Colour" at the bottom of the menu

Click in "Hex #" and enter 000080

Comment: In other words, I can't bulk reset the links to new.

Comment: Not AFAIK, sorry